# Embedding ActiveMQ broker in Spring-MVC Tomcat webapp

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, jms, activemq-classic

I have a small Spring MVC webapp (which embeds ActiveMQ) that is designed to run in a local Tomcat, and reliably message to a queue on a remote ActiveMQ.

All of that's in place, except for the "reliably". At the moment, if the remote site goes down, the send fails dramatically. My send config:

```
<!-- Connection setup -->
<bean id="connectionFactory" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
    p:brokerURL="tcp://backend-server-box:61616" />

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
    p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" 
    p:sessionCacheSize="10" />

<!-- Bean that represents the correct destination on the backend server -->
<bean id="backendDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="jmsQueueName" />
</bean>

<bean id="backendTemplate" 
    class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="cachedConnectionFactory"
    p:defaultDestination-ref="backendDestination" />

<!-- Bean that sends to the correct destination on the backend server -->
<bean id="simpleSender" class="uk.co.mycompany.client.messaging.SimpleSender">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="backendTemplate" />
</bean>
```

I think what I need is a local, persistent broker that the connectionFactory (the first bean defined above) points to, which is aware of the remote broker (a JMS to JMS bridge?) If there's a clear bit of documentation to deal with this I'd be very happy to be pointed at it, but I've had to cobble things together, mostly from the extremely helpful [BruceBlog](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-spring-jmstemplate-to-send-jms.html). Or any direct help would be great.

Thanks

<strike>**Update**. Some fixes:</strike>

1. Eclipse doesn't find the amq namespace properly. [This](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/02/01/invalid-activemq-schema-name-space) is where you find out why that's broken, and it's an easy fix.
2. As Miklos says in a comment below, you need the org.osgi.core-4.1.0.jar in your webapp lib. Get this from the ActiveMQ lib/optional folder.
3. You also need the Apache Commons xbean-spring-3.4.jar. Get it [here](http://ftp.us.xemacs.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/xbean/xbean-spring/3.4/).
4. [This](http://www.func.nl/community/knowledgebase/running-activemq-using-spring) guide got me through the next few hurdles. It's perfect, except in a couple of places attribute names are incorrect (brokername should be brokerName, and physicalname should be physicalName).

**Update 2**. I've answered it properly, below. Doesn't need any of that amq stuff!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how to do it.

### Assumptions

1. You're connecting to a remote destination on **http://destination-box:61616**
2. You'll connect to your local broker via [VM transport](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html), on **vm://localhost:7001**
3. You have two remote queues you want to bridge to: **queue1** and **queue2**

### Pre: namespaces

You need to declare the following namespaces:

```
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
```

### 1. Create a local broker:

```
<bean id="bridgedBroker" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService"
 init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
  <property name="brokerName" value="bridgedBroker"/>
  <property name="persistent" value="true"/>
  <property name="transportConnectorURIs"> 
    <value>vm://localhost:7001</value>
  </property>
  <property name="jmsBridgeConnectors">
    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.JmsQueueConnector">
      <property name="outboundQueueConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
          <property name="brokerURL" 
           value="failover:(tcp://destination-box:61616)?maxReconnectDelay=10" />
        </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="outboundQueueBridges">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.OutboundQueueBridge">
            <constructor-arg value="queue1"/>
          </bean>
          <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.OutboundQueueBridge">
            <constructor-arg value="queue2"/>
          </bean>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

So you're using persistence, activated by a property, and a [Broker Configuration URI](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-configuration-uri.html) to configure retry behaviour. You have to list the name of each remote queue you want to connect to in the **outboundBridgeQueues** list.

### 2. Create broker connection factories

This one connects to the above broker:

```
<bean id="brokerConnectionFactory"
 class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
 p:brokerURL="vm://localhost:7001" />
```

Then wrap it with a CachingConnectionFactory (almost always a [good idea](http://codedependents.com/2010/07/14/connectionfactories-and-caching-with-spring-and-activemq/)):

```
<bean id="cachingBrokerConnectionFactory"
 class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
 p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="brokerConnectionFactory"
 p:sessionCacheSize="10" />
```

### 3. Create local equivalents of the remote destinations

Each destination you’ll be talking to now needs a local representation:

```
<bean id="queue1destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
  <constructor-arg value="queue1" />
</bean>

<bean id="queue2destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
  <constructor-arg value="queue2" />
</bean>
```

### 4. Create JMS templates to be wired into local beans

I’ll just make one for **queue1** here; **queue2** is exactly the same process:

```
<bean id="queue1JMSTemplate"
 class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
 p:connectionFactory-ref="cachingBrokerConnectionFactory"
 p:defaultDestination-ref="queue1destination" />
```

### 5. Use the JMS template

Some sample code:

```
public class SendToQueue1
{
  @Autowired protected JmsTemplate queue1JMSTemplate; 

  public void sendMessage(final String message) throws JMSException
  {
    queue1JMSTemplate.send(new MessageCreator()
    {
      public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException
      {
        return session.createTextMessage(message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And you're done! Not actually too painful, but it took a while to get it working. Hope this helps people in the future; it's a great way to quickly add persistent messaging to a small app.

*Note: this isn't a great way to wire up the class. You'd probably pass in a JMSTemplate from config, so you could use one class definition and wire it into different templates for different queues. I've just done it like this for speed. Just use your Spring instincts :)*

Answer (score 1):

Apache's Active MQ website gives an example on how to embed a broker in Spring: http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html and on how to define a JMS bridge: http://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge.html

Comment: I'm trying :) Got as far as adding the xmlns:amq declaration at the top of the beans file, adding in the xbean-spring-3.4.jar file, and with a simple broker declaration (<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false"><amq:transportConnectors><amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" /></amq:transportConnectors></amq:broker>) I'm now getting a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException, which is because it can't find org/osgi/framework/BundleException, apparently. This is all why I asked the question :)

Comment: Hunting for JAR files and setting up CLASSPATH is painful in Java programming. I found BundleException in org.osgi.core-4.1.0.jar, which is part of the Active MQ 5.3.2 package.